# The meaning of score method in xgboost

Tags: xgboost

I am solving a **regression problem**, and I've set aside a cv data set on which I evaluate my models.

I can easily evaluate my NN network as TensorFlow evaluate() method gives me the sum of all squared errors.
However, xgb provides me with a function - score() that returns me a *number* - 0.7

Firstly, how should I interpret this *number*?
Secondly, how can I make xgb return **a measure of the model that I can interpret**?

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, how should I interpret this number?

From the official [doc](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.score), this number represents the coefficient of determination. It is the proportion of variance of your dependent variable (y) explained by the independent variable (x). Thus, the closer it is to 1, the better your regression line fits the data and the better your model is.

> Secondly, how can I make xgb return a measure of the model that I can interpret?

You can use the predict method from the model and then calculate any measure you want. For example, if you want the sum of squared errors as Tensorflow does :

```
import xgboost as xgb 
model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
ssr = ((predictions - y_test)**2).sum()
```